# My iPhone 4 (model AI332) won't turn on or charge

Tags: iphone

My iPhone's back got smashed and, not liking the look of it, I took it off and used the phone without the back.

Later, I dropped the phone again and the battery came out completely. Although the battery was a bit loose before I dropped it the second time, now it wasn't even in the phone.

I put the battery back in and because it would not turn on, I began charging it. The iPhone started booting up, but then it shut off and restarted. It did this several times before it finally brought up an image showing me to plug it into iTunes.

When I did connect it to iTunes, nothing happened; the iPhone did not light up at all as I plugged it into my laptop.
 I went to a phone repair store, and a gentleman told me it was the battery, but is there any way I can fix this myself and is it definitely the battery?

Comment: Moral to the story: don't take the back off your iPhone; it holds the battery in.

Comment: Get an new iPhone when it comes out. You smashed it two times, maybe connectors got loose. The cost for the repair would only be slightly lower than a new iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is you can:

a) pay someone to test a new battery in the device and tell you if it's just the battery
b) buy a new battery (or one that is so old and used, that it doesn't hold a long charge, but works well enough to restore the device when it's being powered from a computer).

There's no way the internet can do the diagnosis on one device with the details you have provided. We can explain how to test things, how things work but generally refrain from making guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in my opinion is to send it to [UBreakIFix](http://www.ubreakifix.com). They will give you an honest estimate of what's wrong and what it would cost to fix it.

It may be cheap. It may be as much as $200 or equivalent.

I've used them a number of times (unfortunately)...
 They are fast and good. I got my phones back on average in about 2-3 days.

Comment: Is there any reason their service is better than other repair services?

Comment: I probably should have used them as an example. I guess there are other companies but I have no experience with them. I've used UBreakIFix on at least 4 occasions.