# My (unbroken) iPhone won't turn on!

Tags: usb, iphone, charging, power

I have an iPhone 5. The only issue it's had is that the battery life wasn't so great as it once was... until now.

Earlier the battery went flat and it switched to this screen

[image: iphone flat battery]

Totally normal.

So I plugged it into a portable USB battery that I use in situations like this. But after 30 minutes it still didn't turn on. Then I tried it through the original mains plug and 12 hours later it still didn't turn on. Then I plugged it in via a computer's USB port and 8 more hours it still won't turn on.

Now it's been 72 hours and probably 48 of those plugged into power without turning on.

[Unlike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62544/my-iphone-4-model-ai332-wont-turn-on-or-charge) many [others](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200957/iphone-wont-turn-on-and-i-am-unable-to-put-it-into-dfu-mode) who [have](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101093/iphone-wont-turn-on) asked [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199824/iphone-4-won-t-turn-on-or-wake-up) or [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146875/iphone-4-dropped-in-the-toilet-briefly-and-now-it-wont-turn-on-or-be-recognized) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163698/my-iphone-5c-wont-turn-on-it-just-uzzes-while-plugged-in), my [phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173376/iphone-4-wont-turn-on-and-home-button-does-not-work) isn't [damaged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194749/iphone-5s-wont-turn-on-after-water-damage)...

- I've tried holding the power button.
- I've tried holding the power button and home button - for 10 seconds.
- I've tried charging it with different cables.
- I've tried charging it with different power sources.
- I've tried plugging it into a computer running itunes.

How do I get my iPhone running again?

Comment: Also, it recognises that it's plugged in to a power source because the screen changes to just the empty battery.

Comment: What does iTunes say when you plug it in? Nothing?

Comment: @timothymh iTunes doesn't recognise that it's plugged in at all.

Comment: Have you tried [entering recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263)?

Comment: @timothymh I have tried recovery mode, but it doesn't seem to recognise that it's connected to a computer and not just regular power.

Comment: Replace the battery?

Comment: Does the phone also fail to power on if you keep it plugged in while using it?

Answer (score 1):

You should get someone to open up your iPhone, disconnect the battery, and reconnect it. That's where I would start with it, it may be something more serious, but there's a pretty good chance just that the disconnection and reconnection of the battery on the logic board could work. You could try to do it yourself, but it requires taking off the touchscreen (digitizer) assembly, about a dozen small screws, and a few other parts like EMI shields. It's not too difficult, but if you decide to do it, you'll need to buy tools online and repair guides at [iFixit](http://ifixit.com).